# Ordering number and string in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I want to create a binary search tree and it includes numbers and string such that:

- 48 jennifer
- 35 david
- 27 messi
- 3 gomez
- 85 helena etc.

Now, I need to list them as in order. A part of code is here:

```
void OrderedById(struct CustomerBSTNode *temp){
    if(temp != NULL){
        OrderedById(temp->left);
        printf("%d  ", temp->data.ID);
        printf("%s\n",temp->data.name);
        OrderedById(temp->right);
    }
}
```

All code is here:

```
struct Customer{
char *name; 
int ID; 
struct BasketLLNode* baskets; };

struct Product{ 
int ID; 
char *name; 
int price; };
struct CustomerLLNode{
struct Customer data;
struct CustomerLLNode *next;}*HeadCustomer,*TempCustomer;}

struct CustomerBSTNode{
struct Customer data;
struct CustomerBSTNode *left;
struct CustomerBSTNode *right;};
struct CustomerBSTNode *get_node(){
struct CustomerBSTNode *temp;
temp = (struct CustomerBSTNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct CustomerBSTNode));
temp->left = NULL;
temp->right = NULL;
return temp; }

void insert(struct CustomerBSTNode *root, struct CustomerBSTNode *newNode){
if(newNode->data.ID < root->data.ID)    {
    if(root->left == NULL)
    root->left = newNode;
    else
    insert(root->left,newNode); }

if(newNode->data.ID > root->data.ID){
    if(root->right == NULL)
    root->right = newNode;
    else
    insert(root->right,newNode);    }}
void OrderedById(struct CustomerBSTNode *temp){
if(temp != NULL)    {
    OrderedById(temp->left);
    printf("%d  ", temp->data.ID);
    printf("%s\n",temp->data.name);
    OrderedById(temp->right);   }}
int main(){
char ans = 'N';
int key;
struct CustomerBSTNode *new_node, *root, *tmp, *parent,*get_node();
root = NULL;
char CustomerName[25];
while(ans != 'a'){
    printf("Enter Elements: ");
    new_node = get_node();
    scanf("%d",&new_node->data.ID);
    scanf("%s",new_node->data.name);

    if(root == NULL)
    root = new_node;
    else
    insert(root,new_node);
    ans = getch();  }

OrderedById(root);

return 0;}
```

I want the output of this code to be:

- 3 gomez
- 27 messi
- 35 david
- 48 jennifer
- 85 helena

But the code gives:

- 3 helena
- 27 helena
- 35 helena
- 48 helena
- 85 helena

What is my error? It orders by id but the name is the same in all lines.

Comment: Please remove the image and paste the code as text.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `get_node`. It looks like all the nodes use the same address for `data.name`.

Comment: So every time you do `scanf("%s", new_node->data.name);` it's overwriting the string used in all the nodes, and at the end they all have the last name that was entered.

Comment: why 'new_node->data.name' has no & "ampersand operator" ?

Comment: @FirstStep Presumably because `data.name` is a pointer or array. An array automatically decays to a pointer when used as a function argument.

Comment: all codes are below pls control it what are the missing ? i dont use "&" for new_noda->data.name because it is not used for string isnt it ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot guess your way to a solution in C. The code you posted *segfaults* immediately because you have failed to provide any storage for the name you read from `stdin`. You apparently intend to reference the name through `struct Customer name`. `name` is an uninitialized pointer to nowhere.

Further, following your call to `new_node = get_node ();` you provide no reference to any `struct Customer` through the `struct CustomerBSTNode, Customer data` member, which you incorrectly have as a static member of type `struct Customer` instead of a pointer to `struct Customer*`. e.g. you should have:

```
struct CustomerBSTNode {
    struct Customer *data;
    struct CustomerBSTNode *left;
    struct CustomerBSTNode *right;
};
```

(which will require changes to how you reference members of `Customer` throughout the remainder of your code)

You do not validate any of your memory allocations with `malloc` or check the return from `scanf`. How will you know if you even have any memory within which you can store the input you take and how do you know that you have any input to store in the first place? Always, always validate all allocations and all input. e.g.

```
struct CustomerBSTNode *get_node ()
{
    struct CustomerBSTNode *temp;
    if (!(temp = malloc (sizeof *temp))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

and

```
    while (printf ("Enter Elements (age, name): ") &&
           scanf (" %d %24[^\n]%*c", &key, name) == 2) {
```

Your `main` function is so cluttered with unused variables, it is almost impossible to tell what your approach to the problem was. Correcting the immediate problems and reworking `main`, you could arrive at a solution similar to:

```
int main (void) {

    int key;
    char name[MAXNM] = "";
    struct CustomerBSTNode *new_node, *root = NULL;

    while (printf ("Enter Elements (age, name): ") &&
           scanf (" %d %24[^\n]%*c", &key, name) == 2) {

        new_node = get_node ();

        struct Customer *cust;
        if (!(cust = malloc (sizeof *cust))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cust->ID = key;
        cust->name = strdup (name);
        new_node->data = cust;

        if (root == NULL) root = new_node;
        else insert (root, new_node);
    }

    printf ("\n\nElements OrderedById\n\n");
    OrderedById (root);

    return 0;
}
```

Putting all the pieces together, you could do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNM 25

struct Customer {
    char *name;
    int ID;
    struct BasketLLNode *baskets;
};

struct Product {
    int ID;
    char *name;
    int price;
};

struct CustomerLLNode {
    struct Customer *data;
    struct CustomerLLNode *next;
} *HeadCustomer, *TempCustomer;

struct CustomerBSTNode {
    struct Customer *data;
    struct CustomerBSTNode *left;
    struct CustomerBSTNode *right;
};

struct CustomerBSTNode *get_node ()
{
    struct CustomerBSTNode *temp;
    if (!(temp = malloc (sizeof *temp))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void insert (struct CustomerBSTNode *root, struct CustomerBSTNode *newNode)
{
    if (newNode->data->ID < root->data->ID) {
        if (root->left == NULL)
            root->left = newNode;
        else
            insert (root->left, newNode);
    }

    if (newNode->data->ID > root->data->ID) {
        if (root->right == NULL)
            root->right = newNode;
        else
            insert (root->right, newNode);
    }
}

void OrderedById (struct CustomerBSTNode *temp)
{
    if (temp != NULL) {
        OrderedById (temp->left);
        printf (" %2d  %s\n", temp->data->ID, temp->data->name);
        OrderedById (temp->right);
    }
}

int main (void) {

    int key;
    char name[MAXNM] = "";
    struct CustomerBSTNode *new_node, *root = NULL;

    while (printf ("Enter Elements (age, name): ") &&
           scanf (" %d %24[^\n]%*c", &key, name) == 2) {

        new_node = get_node ();

        struct Customer *cust;
        if (!(cust = malloc (sizeof *cust))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cust->ID = key;
        cust->name = strdup (name);
        new_node->data = cust;

        if (root == NULL) root = new_node;
        else insert (root, new_node);
    }

    printf ("\n\nElements OrderedById\n\n");
    OrderedById (root);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/bstordered
Enter Elements (age, name): 48 Jenifer
Enter Elements (age, name): 35 David
Enter Elements (age, name): 25 Messi
Enter Elements (age, name): 3 Gomez
Enter Elements (age, name): 85 Helena
Enter Elements (age, name):

Elements OrderedById

  3  Gomez
 25  Messi
 35  David
 48  Jenifer
 85  Helena
```

Take time to go though the code and understand why the changes that were made -- were made. You have to think through your data handling very carefully and insure each step, each level of building your data structure, takes only fully allocated members, types, etc.. Let me know if you have further questions.

(**note:** you are responsible for `free`ing the memory you allocate.)